# Update MySQL table using data from a text file through Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a text file with four lines, each line contains comma separated values like below file

My file is:

```
    Raj,raj34@myown.com,123455
   kumar,kumar@myown.com,23453
   shilpa,shilpa@myown.com,765468
   suraj,suraj@myown.com,876567
```

and I have a MySQL table which contains four fields

```
  firstname    lastname      email                phno
  ----------  ----------    ---------            --------
   Raj           babu      raj34@hisown.com       2343245
   kumar         selva     kumar@myown.com        23453
   shilpa        murali    shilpa@myown.com       765468
   suraj         abd       suraj@myown.com        876567
```

Now I want to update my table using the data in the above text file through Java.

I have tried using bufferedReader to read from the file and used split method using comma as delimiter and stored it in array. But it is not working. Any help appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far

```
void readingFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File f1 = new File("TestFile.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String strln = null;
                        strln = br.readLine();

            while((strln=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
//              System.out.println(strln);
                                 arr = strln.split(",");
                                 strfirstname = arr[0];
                                 strlastname = arr[1];
                                stremail = arr[2];
                                strphno = arr[3];
                                System.out.println(strfirstname + " " + strlastname + " " + stremail +" "+ strphno);
                        } 

//                        for(String i : arr)
//                        {

//                        }


            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot read from File." + e);
        }

        try
           {
                st = conn.createStatement();
                String query = "update sampledb set email = stremail,phno =strphno where  firstname = strfirstname ";
                st.executeUpdate(query);
                st.close();
                System.out.println("sampledb Table successfully updated.");
            }
             catch(Exception e3)
            {
             System.out.println("Unable to Update sampledb table. " + e3);   
           }

    }
```

and the output i got is:

```
Ganesh Pandiyan ganesh1@myown.com 9591982389
Dass Jeyan jeyandas@myown.com 9689523645
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Gowtham Selvan gowthams@myown.com 9894189423
    at TemporaryPackages.FileReadAndUpdateTable.readingFile(FileReadAndUpdateTable.java:35)
    at TemporaryPackages.FileReadAndUpdateTable.main(FileReadAndUpdateTable.java:72)
Java Result: 1
```

@varadaraj:
This is the code of yours....

```
String stremail,strphno,strfirstname,strlastname;
//    String[] arr;
    Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    void readingFile()
    {
        try {
             BufferedReader bReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TestFile.txt"));
             String fileValues;

            while ((fileValues = bReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] values=fileValues .split(",");
                strfirstname = values[0];
//                strlastname = values[1];
                stremail = values[1];
                strphno = values[2];
                System.out.println(strfirstname + " " + strlastname + " " + stremail +" "+ strphno);
            }
        bReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }
//                        for(String i : arr)
//                        {

//                        }



        try
           {
                st = conn.createStatement();
                String query = "update sampledb set email = stremail,phno =strphno where  firstname = strfirstname ";
                st.executeUpdate(query);
                st.close();
                System.out.println("sampledb Table successfully updated.");
            }
             catch(Exception e3)
            {
             System.out.println("Unable to Update sampledb table. " + e3);   
           }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use a bulk insert of MySQL?

Comment: what is the issue, i mean are you getting any exception?

Comment: What have you done so far please share your effort

Comment: As far as i can see there is a mismatch between the available data and number of columns. 3 data & 4 columns.

Comment: @juergend I want to update my table not insertion.. if I use LOAD DATA INFILE for update then i have to use temporary table. I dont want that to be. I want to update directly from text file to my table.

Comment: @Jabir I have edited my question and shared my code. have a look

Comment: @pappu_kutty   look at the edited question now... i have given you the issue i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public class FileReaderTesting {
    static String stremail;
    static String strphno;
    static String strfirstname;
    static String strlastname;
    static Connection conn;
    static Statement st;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


            try {
                 BufferedReader bReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\fileName.txt"));
                 String fileValues;

                while ((fileValues = bReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] values=fileValues .split(",");
                    strfirstname = values[0];
//                  strlastname = values[1];
                    stremail = values[1];
                    strphno = values[2];
                    System.out.println(strfirstname + " " + stremail +" "+ strphno);

                        st = conn.createStatement();
                        String query = "update sampledb set email = '"+stremail+"',pno = '"+strphno+"' where  firstname = '"+strfirstname+"' ";
                        System.out.println(query);
                        st.executeUpdate(query);
                        st.close();
                        System.out.println("sampledb Table successfully updated.");
                }
            bReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
            catch(Exception e3)
            {
             System.out.println("Unable to Update sampledb table. " + e3);   
           }


    }
}
```

Comment: hey in your file you did't given last name, check your file properly o else delete strlastname = arr[1]; this line in your code

Comment: yeah, i have done that. Still it is showing me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException..where am i wrong?

Comment: try this one its perfectly working for me                 strfirstname = arr[0];
stremail = arr[1];
strphno = arr[2];
System.out.println(strfirstname + " " + stremail +" "+ strphno);

Comment: @KarthiKarthi copy the above edited code, its perfectly working for me

Comment: Change the 
System.out.println(strfirstname + " " + strlastname + " " + stremail +" "+ strphno);
to
System.out.println(strfirstname + " "  + stremail +" "+ strphno);   still your printing strlastname so delete strlastname  from  System.out.println

Comment: I just copied the code and pasted there is no "strlastname" in my code.Also i tried the latest code you added some 14 mins ago...again the same error....

Comment: and also because of the third line in your code...fileValues = bReader.readLine();   it skips the first line and printing only the next three lines..

Comment: Copy the above edited code and try. its perfectly working and i am able to store values also.

Comment: was that updated in the table properly....when i tried your code it reads only the first line and when trying to update in the table it fails and throws nullpointerexception....

Comment: @KarthiKarthi yeah the above edited code updating the values in the table perfectly with out any erorr. you just copy the above edited code and try.

Comment: yes it did...working fine..it reads and updates all the values and finally it throws "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException". So after this point it is not executing the other part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are having looks like a CSV file, you may consider libraries like [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) to help you in reading and parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException upon trying to access at index 1 , i.e at lastname field value, so check whether you have no data at index 1 for any of the list elements in your text file